# Forward button to navigate to an activity

Tags: android

I have two activities that I want to switch between but also preserve the data.  I am currently able to navigate to the Results activity from the main activity and graph some data, I then can press a back button to return to the main activity but if I want to go forward again to the Results activity (graphs) all the data is gone and the graphs are blank.  How should I switch activities?

Forward Button Method from Main Activity:

```
public void NextBtn(View view)  {
  System.out.println("Next Button Pressed in Main Activity");
  Intent next = new Intent(this, Results.class);
  //this extra is used to know what button called Results activity, if the call if from the NextBtn
  //part of the Results activity onCreate method should not be run since it will crash.
  next.putExtra("what", 1); 
  startActivity(next);
}
```

Back Button Method from Results Activity:

```
public void BackBtn (View view) {
  onBackPressed();  
}
```

Complete Results Activity Code:

```
package com.example.test;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.androidplot.series.XYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class Results extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Results Activity Started");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        Intent WhatBtn = getIntent();
        int what = WhatBtn.getIntExtra("what", 0);
        //if next button was pressed, break out of onCreate.
        if (what == 1) {
            System.out.println("In If Statement");
            return;
        }

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double[] gain = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra("gainData");
        double[] phase = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra("phaseData");
        double[] X_axis = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra("Xaxis");

        XYPlot PhasePlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.PhasePlot);
        XYPlot GainPlot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.GainPlot);

        // Create a couple arrays of y-values to plot:
        //loop is needed to get int[] to number[] and to interleave X & Y values
        Number[] gainNumbers = new Number[2*gain.length];
        Number[] phaseNumbers = new Number[2*phase.length];

        for (int i=1; i<=gain.length; i++) {
            gainNumbers[2*(i-1)] = X_axis[i-1];
            gainNumbers[(2*i)-1] = gain[i-1];
            phaseNumbers[2*(i-1)] = X_axis[i-1];
            phaseNumbers[(2*i)-1] = phase[i-1];
        }

        // Turn the above arrays into XYSeries':
        XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(gainNumbers),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
                "Series1");                             // Set the display title of the series

        // same as above
        XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(phaseNumbers), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED, "Series2");

        // Create a formatter to use for drawing a series using LineAndPointRenderer:
        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(
                Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),                   // line color
                Color.rgb(0, 100, 0),                   // point color
                null);                                  // fill color (none)

        // add a new series' to the xyplot:
        GainPlot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

        // same as above:
        PhasePlot.addSeries(series2,
                new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.rgb(0, 0, 200), Color.rgb(0, 0, 100), null));

        // reduce the number of range labels
        GainPlot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);

        // by default, AndroidPlot displays developer guides to aid in laying out your plot.
        // To get rid of them call disableAllMarkup():
        GainPlot.disableAllMarkup();
        //Lable plots
        GainPlot.setRangeLabel("Reflection Coefficient");
        GainPlot.setDomainLabel("Frequency (MHz)");
        PhasePlot.setRangeLabel("Phase (Degrees)");
        PhasePlot.setDomainLabel("Frequency (MHz)");
        PhasePlot.setTitle("Phase");
        GainPlot.setTitle("Gain");
        //Remove Legend
        GainPlot.getLayoutManager().remove(GainPlot.getLegendWidget());
        PhasePlot.getLayoutManager().remove(PhasePlot.getLegendWidget());
        //adust margins to avoid axis being cut off
        GainPlot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingRight(10);
        GainPlot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingTop(4);
        PhasePlot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingRight(10);
        PhasePlot.getGraphWidget().setGridPaddingTop(4);
        // only display whole numbers in domain labels
        GainPlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
        PhasePlot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
    }

    public void start_sweep(View view) {
        //how to call start_sweep method in main activity from results activity
    }

    public void BackBtn (View view) {
        onBackPressed();    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.results, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set android:launchMode="singleTop" in Result activity in Manifest file.
So now, if you've created an activity (Result) once then sending another intent to it won't create a new activity but get previous one to the foreground

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for more info

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this didn't seem to help but I did realize I was over complicating this.  I simply made the NextBtn send the exact same Intent that was called the first time to graph the data.  Just had to make some data global.

Comment: But sending the same data again results in unneeded data flow than just bringing to front the old activity that has data and only need refreshing (bringing to front). But if your solution is sufficient than ok :)